# What are good resources for computer graphics basics?

Tags: graphics

During Flex programming, I recently ran into several questions ([about box models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2758454/are-border-lines-in-the-flash-drawing-api-drawn-inside-or-outside-a-shape), [ways to join lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2806753/why-should-miter-joints-be-slower-than-others) and [misaligning pixels](http://doctype.com/my-lines-align-any-joint-style-other-than-miter) [on doctype]) regarding computer graphics and layout, where I felt that I lacked some basic background on things like

- concepts like the box model
- approaches mapping real numbers to a pixel raster (like font anti-aliasing)
- conventions found across drawing engines, like do you count y coordinates from top or bottom, and why

I feel that reading some basic Wikipedia articles, books or tutorials on these subjects might help in phrasing my questions more specifically and debugging my code more systematically. I have repeatedly found myself writing tiny test apps in Flex, just to find out how the APIs do very basic stuff. My assumption would be that if I knew the right vocabulary and some general concepts, I could solve these questions much faster.

Comment: Related q [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960434/where-can-i-find-computer-graphics-video-lectures).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have much experience in this field myself, but I'd suggest to have a look at

- [Ke-Sen Huang's Home Page](http://kesen.realtimerendering.com/)
- [CG Online Tutorials](http://www.allgraphicdesign.com/graphics/comptutergraphics101.html)
- [The Cornell University's CG page](http://www.graphics.cornell.edu/resources.html)
- [The Arizona State University Introduction to Computer Graphics](http://www.farinhansford.com/dianne/teaching/cse470/references.html)
- [The Brown University Introduction to Computer Graphics](http://www.cs.brown.edu/courses/cs123/resources.htm)